# Maintain <div> 2 to be visible while mouse is on top of <div> 1

Tags: jquery, html, user-interface

I'm trying to make a drop-down menu using two divs, the first `<div>` has the .hover() function which shows the second `<div>`. Since the first div has the .hover() function when I pass my mouse pointer over the second `<div>`, it disappears.

How can I disable the first `<div>`'s .hover() function when my mouse pointer is over the second `<div>`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a containing div that wraps both of your menu divs. When the first menu div is hovered, show the second div - when the containing div is no longer hovered, hide the second div.

Hopefully that makes sense:

```
    function show() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("secondmenu");
    elem.style.display = "block";
    }
    function hide() {
    var elem = document.getElementById("secondmenu");
    elem.style.display = "none";
    }

<div id="container" onmouseout="hide()"><div id="firstmenu" onmouseover="show()">this is the first menu</div><div id="secondmenu" style="display: none;">this is the second menu</div></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, I seem to be out of sorts today. The first <div> should just handle the 'showing' of the second <div> while the second <div> should handle the 'hiding' of itself. XD